# What is actually the danger of using any port below 1024

Tags: networking, network-programming

Everyone knows you shouldn't pick any port lower than 1024, if you are using your own protocol.

That seems like common sense. Less chances for a collisions, and I guess some lower ports are reserved.

But what is actually the danger of using, say, port 7 in my server, instead of random port 4921?

What is the worst possible scenario? Is there anything out there that actually uses these ports?

Answer (score 4):

There's no danger. A port is simply a number used to multiplex the communication happening via a given IP, because TCP sockets, for example, are described by the tuple `(srcaddr, srcport, dstaddr, dstport)`. There are no dangers and no *worst case scenarios*.

In some system port numbers below 1024 require administrative privileges to bind to because they are [well-known ports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers).

BTW, port 7 is for the echo protocol.

Comment: As long as the number does not matter, I suggest you pick a number easy to remeber but greater than 1024, like 2222, 3232, 4444, ...